# Next js alias path not work on scss module

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sass, alias

I use scss module on my next.js project and I have a problem with my alias path import in scss.
when I  try to import my util.scss in other scss modules the web storm drow a red line under the path
my import statement is `@import "@/styles/utils.scss";`
the import is working and the style is getting applied but Webstorm do not understand it
even vs code can't find the path when I click on the import statement